# SQL to show 1 for unique and 0 for reapeat

Tags: sql, sql-server

looking for a quick solution on SQL...

I used to have a clunky formula in excel: =IF(COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)>1,0,COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)) to print 1 for unique item and 0 for a repeat.

Then moved to =1-(C1-C2) and that kinda did the job... Not an accurate one Now looking for an SQL that could do a similar job... The example below for result needed:

```
NUMBER         UNIQUE
6573455300000  1
6573455300000  0
6573455300000  0
6573455300000  0
6573411981080  1
6573411981080  0
6573411981080  0
6573411981080  0
```

Does anyone know any kind of code to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you mean "unique", right? I think you mean "first instance". 6573455300000 is not unique in your set.

Comment: Yep, you're right Steven, more like a first instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `row_number()`:

```
select 
    col
  , [first] = case when row_number() over (partition by col order by (select 1)) > 1 then 0 else 1 end
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FWA89661

returns:

```
+---------------+-------+
|      col      | first |
+---------------+-------+
| 6573411981080 |     1 |
| 6573411981080 |     0 |
| 6573411981080 |     0 |
| 6573411981080 |     0 |
| 6573455300000 |     1 |
| 6573455300000 |     0 |
| 6573455300000 |     0 |
| 6573455300000 |     0 |
+---------------+-------+
```

Comment: snap! (essentially).. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions.  In your case, you seem to want the first row and mark that, so `row_number()` looks like the solution:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by number order by ?) = 1
             then 1 else 0 end
        end) as flag
from t;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering (which is first).  If you want just one row but don't care which, then you can use `order by number` or `order by (select null)`.

`UNIQUE` is a SQL keyword (think "unique index"), so it is a bad name for a column.  That is why I changed to the generic `flag`, although you might prefer `first_row_flag` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
 [number],
 case when rown = 1 then 1 else 0 end as [unique]
FROM
(
 SELECT
  [number], row_number() OVER(partition by [number] order by [number]) as rown 
 FROM 
  t
) a
```

This doesn't strictly have to be done using a subquery but it's unlikely to make any difference to the overall performance, so it's arranged like this to help you see what is going on. If you run just the inner subquery in isolation you'll see that the most important work is done by row_number; essentially the data is partitioned into buckets based on the value of [number] something like a group by, but it doesn't suppress repeated values. Within the partition each occurrence of [number] is numbered with an incrementing counter. When a different value of [number] is encountered the numbering restarts from 1. The order by clause is just there because sql server demands you have one, and we don't know anything else about your table but if there's something else about your data where one of these occurrences would be more ideal to single out to be labelled with [unique]=1, try and find a way to make it so that row is sorted into position 1; a typical use of this pattern is "latest record" in which case the order by part would be `[datecolumn] DESC`

Once you have an increment of counter per number that resets itself, all we need to do is use a standard case / else statement to make it a 1 when it's 1 otherwise 0 to match your result desired

Comment: Who else offered an answer with an explanation? Gordon didn't, SqlZim didn't.. Yet I don't see you downvoting them.. I think you just looked at my post, saw that it only contained a code block, saw that the others wrote some non-code words (none of which are an explanation of how the query works) and decided to get all sheriff on me..

Comment: You are making incorrect assumptions: I didn't downvote your answer, that was someone else. I came across your answer in the review queue (which, btw, doesn't show the other answers unless you go to the full question), decided to post a comment how **you** can **improve** your answer (you know, something that might actually attract upvotes). And although both other answers aren't great, they at least contain more than just a code dump, they both include a hint at the importance of the use of `row_number`, and SqlZim demonstrates the result, and Gordan adds some explanation on how to use it.

Comment: Hi Mark, I forgot about the limited context view of the review queue and appreciate the extended explanation, thanks. Sorry for jumping to the DV conclusion

Answer (score 0):

```
select  t.Number,case when t.num=1 then t.num else 0 end [Unique] from(
select Number,row_number() over (partition by number order by number) num from MyTbl)t
order by t.Number
```